# Container component props error

Tags: reactjs

I am currently learning react.

I have a container component:

```
  <SceneSelectNumber
    goBack={this.goBack}
    onChangeNumber={sceneConfig.onChangeNumber}
    selectedNumberValue={this.props.daysInAweek}
    onDone={this.onDone}
    renderHowMuch
    helpMeCalculate
    sceneConfig={sceneConfig}
  />
```

Which contains all the related child components:

```
  <Flexible>
    <LYDSceneContainer
      goBack={this.props.goBack}
      subSteps={this.props.subSteps}>
      <Flexible>
        <LYDSceneQuestion {...this.props.sceneConfig.question[0]} />
        <LYDSelectNumber
          selectedNumberValue={this.props.selectedNumberValue[0]}
          onChangeNumber={this.props.onChangeNumber}
        />
      </Flexible>
      {this.props.renderHowMuch && this.renderHowMuch()}
      {this.props.helpMeCalculate && this.renderHelpMeCalculateButton()}
    </LYDSceneContainer>

    <NextButton
      onPress={this.props.onDone}
      disabled={!this.props.selectedNumberValue}
      fullWidth
    />
  </Flexible>
```

However, as I need to add another child component, I am storing data in an array of objects `sceneConfig`.

```
 question: [
    {
      text: ['on how many of the last 7 days', 'did you have a drink?'],
    },
    {
      text: [
        'On your drinking days',
        'how many units of alcohol did you typically drink?',
      ],
    },
  ],
```

To display the new data, I have to change my `LYDSceneQuestion` component from,         `{props.text}` to `{props.text[1]}`

```
<View style={[styles.container, props.style]}>
  <Text style={styles.textRowNormal}>
    {props.text[0]}
  </Text>
  <Text style={styles.textRowBold}>
    {props.text[1]}
  </Text>
</View>
```

This breaks my other pages that use the component.

How can I change my component so it doesn't break other pages that use it?

I have changed my data from:

```
const sceneConfig = {
  question: {
    text: 'string, 'string')],
  },
```

To:

```
  question: [
    {
      text: ['on how many of the last 7 days', 'did you have a drink?'],
    },
    {
      text: [
        'On your drinking days',
        'how many units of alcohol did you typically drink?',
      ],
    },
  ],
  selectNumber: [() => {}, () => {}],
  onChangeNumber: [
    number => {
      const data = { [field]: number };
      this.props.dispatch(assessmentActions.updateAssessment(step, data));
    },
    number => {
      const data = { [field]: number };
      this.props.dispatch(assessmentActions.updateAssessment(step, data));
    },
  ],
```

Comment: It very hard to understand the context of your issue from this example. You can use a ternary operator to do conditional rendering if required.

Comment: Something like this,     `{props.text ? props.text : props.text[0]}` ?

Comment: If you want to be sure if props.text exists and is a String or Array you can use this ```{props.text && props.text.constructor === String ? props.text : props.text[0] }```. If you have more items you should map the array with *Array.prototype.map* instead of calling items by index directly.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this

```
<View style={[styles.container, props.style]}>
  {props.text.map(function(item, i){
     return (
       <Text style={ i=0 ? styles.textRowNormal : styles.textRowBold }>
         {item}
       </Text>
     )
  })}
</View>
```

**Update 1**

assuming you are passing `quesion` as a props

1) create `stateless` component

```
const ViewText = ({props}) => {
    return(
        {props.data.text.map(function(item, i){
         return (
           <Text style={ i=0 ? styles.textRowNormal : styles.textRowBold }>
             {item}
           </Text>
         )
      })}
    )
};
```

2) Created function to check isArray

```
function isArray(obj) {
    return (typeof obj !== 'undefined' &&
            obj && obj.constructor === Array);
}
```

3) Container will be

```
<View style={[styles.container, props.style]}>
  {if(isArray(this.props.quesion)?
      this.props.quesion.map(function(obj){
          <ViewText data={obj}/>
      }):
     <ViewText data={this.prop.quesion}/>
  }
</View>
```

Comment: Thanks, sometimes its an array rather than a property value, can I check for that?

Comment: test data please..?

Comment: i18n.t('onYourDrinkingDays') returns what ? string or object ?